# OpenGL multiple textures with VBOs

Tags: opengl, textures, vbo, multitexturing

I'm trying to figure out how to render an object (a cube) with different textures for each face. For simplicities sake, I have 2 textures that are applied to 3 faces of the cube each. I understand that I should be using texture arrays with 3 coordinates to represent the relevant texture to be used. I'm just unsure of how to do this and how to code my fragment shader.

Here is the relevant part of my `init()` function:

```
final String textureName = model.getTextures().get(i).textureName;
final FileTexture textureGenerator = new FileTexture(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(textureName),
                true, context);
textureId = textureGenerator.getTextureId();
width = textureGenerator.getWidth();
height = textureGenerator.getHeight();
textureMap.put(model.getTextures().get(i).matName, textureId);
context.getGL().glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
context.getGL().glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
```

I am slightly confused here however because the *Orange Book* (OpenGL Shading Language) gives examples in which the `glActiveTexture` and `glBindTexture` is used but the [GLSL common mistakes](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_%3a_common_mistakes#Enable%5FOr%5FNot%5FTo%5FEnable) says you shouldn't do this.

From there, my `display()` function looks like this:

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getVertexBufferObject());
gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNoOfVertices() * 3 * 4, getVertices(), GL.GL_STREAM_DRAW);

gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getTexCoordBufferObject());
gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNoOfVertices() * 2 * 4, getTexCoords(), GL.GL_STREAM_DRAW);

gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, getIndicesBufferObject());
gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNoOfIndices() * 4, getIndices(), GL.GL_STREAM_DRAW);

gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getColorBufferObject());
gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNoOfVertices() * 4 * 4, getColors(), GL.GL_STREAM_DRAW);

layerTextureShader.use(gl);

gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getVertexBufferObject());
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mask ? getMaskColorBufferObject() : getColorBufferObject());
gl.glColorPointer(4, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

gl.glClientActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

gl.glClientActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE1);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, getIndicesBufferObject());

final int count = getNoOfIndices();
gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

gl.glClientActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

gl.glClientActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE1);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

layerTextureShader.release(gl);
```

I am unsure of what to put in my GLSL shaders. My vertex shader has the standard `gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;` and my fragment shader looks like:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
}
```

How do I instruct the fragment shader on which texture to use? I assume it's when I'm populating the vertex, index, textures buffers etc and I do it by passing in this 3rd texture coordinate for each point? Is the value of this 3rd coordinate the value of the relevant texture coordinate?
I hope my question makes sense and thanks for any help.
Chris

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that I need to use glTexImage3D instead of glTexImage2D when I'm creating my textures and then access them as above using the 3rd coordinate as the index?

Comment: No, much of what you currently do will stay the same. I will show you a cube map sample here shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [cube map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping). In OpenGL, you can define six textures at once (representing the size sides of a cube) and map them using 3D texture coordinates instead of the common 2D texture coordinates. For a simple cube, the texture coordinates would be the same as the vertices' respective normals. (If you will only be texturing plane cubes in this manner, you can consolidate normals and texture coordinates in your vertex shader, too!) Cube maps are much simpler than trying to bind six distinct textures simultaneously the way you are doing right now.

```
GLuint mHandle;
glGenTextures(1, &mHandle); // create your texture normally

// Note the target being used instead of GL_TEXTURE_2D!
glTextParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTextParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTextParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTextParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, mHandle);

// Now, load in your six distinct images. They need to be the same dimensions!
// Notice the targets being specified: the six sides of the cube map.
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data3);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data5);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
    format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data6);

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
glTextParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

// And of course, after you are all done using the textures...
glDeleteTextures(1, &mHandle);
```

Now, when doing your shaders, you need the vertex shader to accept and/or pass 3D coordinates (vec3) instead of 2D coordinates (vec2).

```
// old GLSL style
attribute vec3 inTextureCoordinate;
varying vec3 vTextureCoordinate;

// more recent GLSL
in vec3 inTextureCoordinate;
out vec3 vTextureCoordinate;
```

In this example, your vertex shader would simply assign vTextureCoordinate = inTextureCoordinate. Your fragment shader then needs to accept that texture coordinate and sample the cube map uniform.

```
uniform samplerCube cubeMap;
...
gl_FragColor = textureCube(cubeMap, vTextureCoordinate);
```

Whew! That was a lot. Did I leave anything out?